# Is there a way to block the chrome://extensions page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there any way we can block the user from accessing the chrome://extensions page with an extension or other means? like a chrome flag, I am running chrome thru terminal and load the extensions thru --load-extensions flag. and I want to hide or block the user from uninstalling an extension.

Comment: You could have used chrome.tabs.onCreated and then chrome.tabs.remove but it won't help you because the user can trivially remove the extension by right-clicking its icon in the browser's toolbar.

Comment: how would I do that on  onCreated? i found a way to prevent them from uninstalling an extension through an extension too, so I just want to block them from accessing the chrome://extensions page to avoid them from disabling the extension. :)

Comment: Is this for some enterprise requirement? Seems weird to block access to what goes on your browser... Maybe better to create some sort of ping mechanism and flag users server-side who disable the extension.

Comment: @cameck doing the flagging with server-side is somewhat overkill, so we are looking for a simple workaround, it's custom one only applicable for some user, actually we are wrapping it with electron app, and let the electron app set the flags and extensions and responsiblefor running the browser.